# building lib with pybind11 linking other shared lib

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

My project reply on a SO file which I will make it by `cmake` installing under my project folder.And it works files when I run `python setup.py install`

But I install it by pip, because pip will copy the project into a tmpfile,It will be removed after installed and the SO file also be removed. Hence, when I import my project, it fails for not finding the SO file.

Of course, I can install the SO file to `/usr/local/lib`, but I don't want to

Anyone has idea to solve it?

Comment: https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#advanced-interface-library-target  might be useful

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help

Answer (score 5):

You need to make your shared library discoverable at run time. Same rules applies as for regular C++ executable.

There are several options here (list might be incomplete):

- Place shared library along with other shared libraries (e.g. `/usr/lib/`)
- Add custom conf with path to shared library to `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/my_lib.conf`
- Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before calling python interpreter
- Use `LD_PRELOAD` to run python interpreter
- Set path to shared library as `RPATH` attribute of pybind11 module.

I personally [use](https://github.com/sizmailov/pyxmolpp2/blob/master/setup.py#L42-L44) the latter option: it allows me to use virtualenv freely

Comment: Yes, I know.The problem is that I don't know how to store the so file.I don't want to put it into `/usr/local/lib` folder.I want to put it into installed folder such as `~/.local/lib/python3.x/sites-package/example.egg/`

Comment: @binbin In the linked setup.py  a `-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE` set to the root of extension, so it's automatically found by `find_packages()` and installed to `site-packages`

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [auditwheel](https://github.com/pypa/auditwheel#overview) if you have a wheel package.

> `auditwheel repair`: copies these external shared libraries into the wheel itself, and automatically modifies the appropriate RPATH entries such that these libraries will be picked up at runtime. This accomplishes a similar result as if the libraries had been statically linked without requiring changes to the build system. Packagers are advised that bundling, like static linking, may implicate copyright concerns.